# PATCH Method is not working with an Error "Bad Request"

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, rest-api

I have an apex callout and LWC that retrieve case records from another org and display them in a data table with an edit feature.

- It's displaying the records but when I am trying to edit a record and save it, It has an error "400 Bad requests".
- Right now I can't identify what's causing that error.
- I think it's on the request but I can't figure out what part of the request causing it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

This JS is used in updating fields

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import updateCase from '@salesforce/apex/calloutRequest.updateCase';
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class CaseEditForm extends LightningElement {
    @api serializedCase;

    @track deserializedCaseData;
    @track newSubject;
    @track newStatus;

    statusOptions = [
        { label: 'New', value: 'New' },
        { label: 'In Progress', value: 'In Progress' },
        { label: 'Closed', value: 'Closed' },
        { label: 'Closed Resolved', value: 'Closed Resolved' },
        { label: 'Closed Duplicate', value: 'Closed Duplicate' },
        { label: 'Closed Complete', value: 'Closed Complete' },
        { label: 'Resolved', value: 'Resolved' },
        { label: 'Closed - Incomplete', value: 'Closed - Incomplete' }
    ];
    
    get isDataAvailable() {
        return !!this.deserializedCaseData;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        if (this.serializedCase) {
            this.deserializedCaseData = JSON.parse(this.serializedCase);
            console.log(this.deserializedCaseData);
        }
    }
    
    handleSubjectChange(event) {
        this.newSubject = event.target.value;
    }
    
    handleStatusChange(event) {
        this.newStatus = event.target.value;
    }

    handleSave(){
        let updatedData = {
            Id: this.deserializedCaseData.Id,
            CaseNumber: this.deserializedCaseData.CaseNumber,
            Subject: this.newSubject,
            Status: this.newStatus
        };
        
        let updatedDataJSON = JSON.stringify(updatedData);
        console.log(updatedDataJSON);
        
       updateCase({ caseId: this.deserializedCaseData.Id, updatedCaseData: updatedDataJSON })
            .then(result => {
                if (result === 'Success') {
                    console.log('Update successful');
                } else {
                    console.error('Update failed:', result);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error calling Apex method:', error);
            });
    
    }
}
```

and this is my Apex method that executes the Callout to update the specific case record.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String updateCase(String caseId, String updatedCaseData) {
        System.debug('caseId: ' + caseId);
        System.debug('updatedCaseData: ' + updatedCaseData);
        String endpoint = 'callout:*NameCredential*/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/case/'+caseId;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('PATCH');
        String autho = 'Bearer {!$*NameCredential*.OAuthToken}';
        req.setHeader('Authorization', autho);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');        
        req.setBody(updatedCaseData);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug(res.getStatusCode());

        if (res.getStatusCode() == 204) {
            return 'Success';
        } else {
            String errorMessage = res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus();
            System.debug(errorMessage);
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling out versus updating the Case directly via DML?

Comment: @identigral  Because I am updating records from another org.

Answer (score 1):

```
String autho = 'Bearer {!$*NameCredential*.OAuthToken}';
```

Should be:

```
String autho = 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}';
```

Any of the merge fields starting with `$Credential` are literal merge values. Only the `callout:*NamedCredential*` part is dynamic based on the chosen Named Credential. Also, if you're using "Generate Authorization Header" in the Named Credential, you don't need to specify the `Authorization` header manually.